# CakePHP and HABTM Model Limit Error

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I've got a series of Post models that hasAndBelongsToMany Media models. In certain function calls inside of the Post model, I don't need to retrieve the entire list of Media models. However, when I use the following code:

```
$this->unbindModel( array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array('Media')) );

// Rebind to get only the fields we need:
$this->bindModel(
        array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array(
            'Media' => array(
                'className' => 'Media',
                'joinTable' => 'media_posts',
                'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'media_id',
                'limit' => 1, 
                'fields' => array('Media.type', 'Media.path', 'Media.title')
            )
        )
    )
);
$this->find('all', $params);
```

This limit only works on one of the first retrieved Post model and all following Post models have no associated Media:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Profile] => Array
                (
                )

            [Media] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => photo
                            [path] => ''
                            [title] => ''
                        )

                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Profile] => Array
                (
                )

            [Media] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not use the [containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable)

```
// you would probably want the next line in the app_model ot be able to use it with all models
$this->Post->actsAs = array('Containable')
$params['conditions'] = array(
);
$params['contain'] = array(
    'Media' => array(
        'fields' => array(
            'type', 'path', 'title'
        ),
        'limit' => 1
    )
);
$this->Post->find('all', $params);
```

---

### EDIT:

Just tried that and got this sql (Module <-> Tag):

```
SELECT `Module`.`id` FROM `modules` AS `Module` WHERE 1 = 1
```

and

```
SELECT `Tag`.`id`, `ModulesTag`.`module_id`, `ModulesTag`.`tag_id` 
FROM `tags` AS `Tag` 
JOIN `modules_tags` AS `ModulesTag` 
  ON (`ModulesTag`.`module_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AND `ModulesTag`.`tag_id` = `Tag`.`id`) 
WHERE `Tag`.`belongs_to` = 'Module' 
ORDER BY `Tag`.`name` ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

obviously that cannot return the wanted result, as you would have to do a query for each Module result (which then again would result in way too many queries).

As a conclusion I would return all Tags (in my example) as the overhead in too many result rows is better than the overhead of too many queries..

Comment: That's it! I actually used the containable behavior before on the Post model, but I didn't realize that I could do the limit there. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I take it back. That only seems to work on find('first') calls, not on find('all') for the Media model. This does not work for any of the other HABTM related models I deal with. Any ideas?

Comment: You know, I came to the same conclusion after comparing some of the same myself: just ignore the overhead since it is less than the overhead of retrieving just one associated model. Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 1):

Cake fetches all the Habtm-related records in one batch query and then assembles them into the results array afterwards. Any additional conditions you specify in the association will be used as is in the query, so it'll look something like this:

```
SELECT … FROM Media WHERE Media.id in (1, 2, 3, …) LIMIT 1
```

So it'll only retrieve a single HABTM model.

There's no apparently easy solution for this. Maybe you could think about the original premise again and why the "first" (`LIMIT 1`) record is supposedly the right one, maybe you can find a different condition to query on.

Failing that, you could rebind your models so Media has a `hasMany` relationship to `medias_posts`, the pivot table. For hasMany and belongsTo queries, Cake automatically does `JOIN` queries. You could use a `GROUP BY` clause then, which would give you the desired result:

```
SELECT … FROM Media JOIN medias_posts … GROUP BY medias_posts.post_id
```

You might also want to experiment with passing the `'join'` parameter with the query, to achieve that effect without extensive rebinding.

```
$this->Media->find('all', array('join' => array(…), …));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->yourModel->hasAndBelongsToMany['Media'] = false; // or null
```

And then set your HABTM association manually

```
$this->yourModel->hasAndBelongsToMany['Media'] = array(........);
```

Or simply modify the association without nulling it:

```
$this->yourModel->HABTM['Media']['fields'] = array(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP has a very powerful tool for this [containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable)