# CakePHP containable HABTM limit

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-2.5, containable, cakephp-2.x

According to the second sentence on the [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) section of the Cookbook, `contain()` supports the `limit` clause.

> A new addition to the CakePHP 1.2 core is the ContainableBehavior. This model behavior allows you to filter and limit model find operations.

I'm Using CakePHP 2.5.

I have two models: Product and Category (HABTM relation).

**The relations for Product:**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Category' => array(
        'className' => 'Category',
        'joinTable' => 'categories_products',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'category_id',
    ),
);
```

**The relations for Category:**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Product' => array(
        'className' => 'Product',
        'joinTable' => 'categories_products',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'product_id',
    ),
);
```

I’m trying do use `limit` as follows:

```
$cats = $this->Category->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'id',
        'parent_id'
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Product' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'id',
                'name',
            ),
            'limit' => 3,
            'order' => array('created DESC'),
        ),
    ),
));
```

The result is that overall only 3 products are selected. Not 3 product per category. The containable behavior is properly loaded. How do I get 3 products per category?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use `'limit'` on HABTM relationships. For performance reasons, CakePHP builds a single query to fetch all the HABTM records, which are later recursively assigned to the parent record key in the output array.

If you apply a LIMIT clause, it will result in CakePHP only fetching a limited number of associated Products, as you have noticed.

The [HABTM section in the Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) should probably be amended to remove `'limit'` as an option, or clarify its intended use.

See this answer for further information:

- [CakePHP and HABTM Model Limit Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255097/cakephp-and-habtm-model-limit-error/2256174#2256174)